# Calculate the area that the following graphs form

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I have been trying and trying to solve the following problem (I even used wolframalpha as an extra help, but no success, and I have like 100 calculations in my notebook):

The Task:

Calculate the area that the following graphs form: 
$$y= \frac{ \left| x \right| }{2}, y= \frac{1}{x^2+1}, y= \frac{1}{4}$$

This is the graph of all three functions:

[image]

So, the area I need to calculate is:

[image]

What I did:
 I divided this area in two parts, so we have: $S=S_{1}+ S_{2}$

[image]

Then I first calculated $S_{1}$ and after $S_{2}$

$$S_{1}= \int_1^1(-\frac{ \left| x \right| }{2}+\frac{1}{x^2+1})$$

...and here I stopped...

--> I don't know how to integrate $|x|$, when I type that in wolframalpha I get $\frac{1}{2} x^2 sgn(x)+c$. What is that sgn(x)?? Can I calculate without it? (I've never seen or used it).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just break your integral up at 0, and let $|x|=-x$ when $x$ is negative, and $|x|=x$ when $x$ is positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break up an integral involving $|x|$ into two integrals, one where $x\geq 0$ and use $x$ for $|x|$, and another where $x\leq0$ and use $-x$ for $|x|$.

If you call your functions $f(x) = |x|/2$, $g(x) = 1/(x^2+1)$, and $h(x) = 1/4$, then you want

$\int_{-1}^{-1/2}(g(x)-f(x))dx + \int_{-1/2}^{0}(g(x)-h(x))dx + \int_{0}^{1/2}(g(x)-h(x))dx + \int_{1/2}^{1}(g(x)-f(x))dx$

using the appropriate replacements for $f(x)$ on the two inner intervals as I mentioned.

Comment: Is the solution $\frac{4\pi-3}{8}$, then?

Comment: You want the area bounded by all three curves, right? So you don't want to include anything below $y=1/4$ (none of what you called $S_2$), right?

Comment: I got $\frac{\pi}{2} -1$